# Visa preparation for the postdoc will take weeks. Can I start research (with the PI?)

Tags: research-process, postdocs, university, job

As it's mentioned in the title. I am going to receive a formal letter this week. During my meeting with HR, they told me the visa will take 12 weeks so we can agree on the start-date at the point. My question is this: I really want to be successful in my postdoc and I want to do research as soon as possible, can I email tell the PI about this? (to get information about their current research step, etc.) or I should keep doing research and reading on my own and wait until everything is official?

Comment: You certainly could go to a University library and start reading papers related to your postdoc. If your postdoc don't happen, you just have lost some time...

Comment: In some cases the university may be required to employ someone who is physically present in the country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can act active and send an email with suggestions to start working remotely. What does that mean in terms of the salary? Do you expect to get paid for that work? That point perhaps should be clarified.

Comment: Thank you, I don't expect anything to be honest. My main drive is to provide results and build my profile, but I am not sure how the PI will react to that: Even if I do clarify that for the salary, some people don't want to work with people who want to work for free..

Comment: Your case is not just "some people who want to work for free". You are going to be a part of the group soon, and that is YOUR research, and you are the one who is the most interested in getting results as soon as you can. So I don't see any objection to emailing the PI

Comment: -1. This answer obscures important information about it often being illegal to work with or without pay without a visa, and that's without even touching on the ethical problems of offering to work for free.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- As long as OP is not an employee, he doesn't work *for* them, but *with* them--it's a collaboration. Collaborations are usually not compensated (who would pay whom anyways?), not subject to labor laws and also not seen as ethically problematic.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper there are many things in the Academia that are not seen as ethically problematic, but they absolutely are...

Comment: @EarlGrey And why is the thing in this case one of them? Collaboration is the norm in most creative fields. The main ethical issue in collaboration is that it must lead to fair credit---in the case of academia, authorship, according to the relevant guidelines.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Creative fields, exactly. The main ethical issue is that work for free is work for free. If a collaboration was just selling twice the same product, I would have nothing against. Since usually it is workload that trickles down to PhDs and the likes, I have a lot against. On one hand, research hours (and wages of 99% of the researchers) are closely linked to a specific project/grant. On the other hand one *is* *expected* to collaborate... otherwise he/she would not have a succesful career. Are collaboration hours allocated in the project time? of course not!

Comment: @lighthousekeeper If it was a collaboration in the true sense of the word, then the OP wouldn't be asking these questions at all. Having dealt with similar visa issues, the authorities are smart enough to know what a "collaboration" is vs. "starting work early for free" is. The host university's legal department will tell the supervisor not to let them do *anything*. The OP could for-realsies collaborate in their current position (if any). The relevant authorities probably also don't care much if the host sends a reading list.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I think it's the other way around: If OP had been aware that every act of working together is a collaboration, he wouldn't have asked the question. Without knowing the specifics of your case it's hard to say if it applies here. What I do know for sure is PIs in academia often hire their collaborators - it's quite natural to hire people whose work style you know. It's unclear on what basis an authority would distinguish hiring cases like that from the case at hand.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper You cannot work for an employer in your host country without a visa. If you are employed in your home country, you could call it a collaboration. If you are not employed, you cannot and should not work for free. If the OP is not employed in their home country and tries to work for free in their host country, they are endangering their visa. This answer does not mention that.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I believe that none of this applies here for the reasons I explained earlier.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Well, you'd be wrong.

Answer (score 12):

[Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, this is not legal advice]

As Thomas mentioned in his [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166497/visa-preparation-for-the-postdoc-will-take-weeks-can-i-start-research-with-the#comment447805_166507), generally, without a visa you cannot be legally employed in the country of the university, this includes remote work from abroad. In addition to that, at least in some countries, it is **illegal** to do work that is normally paid, **even if you are not getting paid** for it, unless you have a proper work permit. I guess, the logic is that you enter the labour market by doing work and not by getting paid.

So be careful and precise in your requests. Starting working on the project remotely, before your visa is ready and valid, is probably against the law (and your future boss will share some responsibility for this). However, simply asking for suggested reading *before* you started working on the project itself is probably okay. I suppose your PI would be happy to give those suggestions even if your visa fell through or you hadn't signed the contract to begin with.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am aware that it can create some problems regardless of what I want or what the PI wants, but for me I consider this risky if I started receiving the exact same responsibilities that I would receive when I have the visa, which is crazy. What I really want is to be included scientifically (could be reading articles, assisting seminars, etc), since these are "public" activities.. I really see no harm.

Comment: @U.User I do not see any problems from the academic research point of view: a reasonable PI is also interested in faster progress of their project. The discussion seems to drift towards the visa and legality issues, because for many these are red flags and caution is warranted. This is why if you email "Can I start doing some work while my visa is being processed?" you can receive a negative answer. You mentioned "assisting seminars" - it sounds like a being responsible for coordination, which is something an employee would normally do. Also not clear how it benefits your research.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if "assisting" were intended to mean "attending" (because of French "assister").

Comment: I believe that the premise of @thomas's comment is wrong. You do not need to have a visa for country X if you work in country Y, even if the employer is in country X. That would be absurd: No company could, in that case, contract with self-employed individuals in other countries for certain services.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Contractors generally have fewer legal protections than employees. Thus there are laws that prevent classifying employees as contractors (and companies like Uber spend many millions of dollars fighting against such laws). Thus you cannot reclassify employees as contractors to evade immigration law.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Here we are talking about a standard postdoc contract, which is a contract of employment between a university (the employer) and a postdoc (the employee). I conclude this from OP mentioning HR, who deal or assist them with their visa. I personally would be interested in hearing your (or anyone else's) account of a university hiring a research as an individual contractor or self-employed.

Comment: I think that this answer does not apply: As long as OP is not employed, he does not work *for* the PI, but *with* them. It's a collaboration situation, which is the default way of working in academia.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper _"As long as OP is not employed, he does not work for the PI"_ - I will respond to your truism with one of mine: OP should not be employed before they are allowed to. The important point is that the difference between "OP is not employed" and "OP is employed without proper paperwork (illegally)" is defined not by one's imagination, but by factual circumstances.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I will expand my comment, in case it is not clear. You are implying that the line between "working for" and "working with" is blurred, therefore OP can engage in research activities with his/her prospective institution arguing that they were merely "collaborating" while the visa was being processed, and started working as an employee only once the visa was done. The problem is that no immigration officer will buy that, and no HR worth his salt will risk it. What you think is "OP not employed" others will regard as "OP employed without paperwork (illegally)".

Comment: @paperskilltrees That's more clear. But I wasn't implying that the line between "working for" and "working with" is blurred - quite the opposite, I say that its quite clear: before starting the appointment, they are only working with. Once employed, they are working with *and* working for. On which basis do you assert that an immigration officer will not understand this difference?

Comment: "without a visa you cannot be legally employed in the country of the university, this includes remote work from abroad" What? No. Visas are about traveling and what you can do while traveling. You don't need a visa to work remotely if you never step foot in the country. There might be other labor laws involved depending on which countries, but e.g. in the US it's perfectly fine to hire people to work abroad: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/us-companies-can-legally-hire-foreigners-living-other-rich-mba

Comment: @lighthousekeeper  _"I say that its quite clear: before starting the appointment, they are only working with. Once employed, they are working with and working for. On which basis do you assert that an immigration officer will not understand this difference?"_ What exactly is this difference between "not started appointment yet" and "employed without proper documentation (illegally)"? In either case the employee does not have a contract.

Comment: @user3067860 First I wanted to thank you for the link, but I changed my mind after spending 30 minutes on checking its content. Under the header "No U.S. Immigration Visa Required", the blogger refers to 3 sources. None of them is a government agency or legislation. The first two, upon inspection, **do not say that the visa is not required**, as the blogger claims. The 3rd reference is another random blogger making a claim without any support at all! Basically, the guy made up the whole thing and copied and pasted Homeland Security logo into his blogpost to impress gullible and naive readers.

Comment: @user3067860 In any case "if you never step foot in the country" is not the OP's case.

Comment: @paperskilltrees The OP needs a visa to enter the US. Until that time, "visa" does not apply to them. Visa, n., "an endorsement on a passport indicating that the holder is allowed to enter, leave, or stay for a specified period of time in a country". https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Avisa

Comment: @paperskilltrees Do you have anything saying that someone _does_ need a visa to work remotely for a US company (not while they're physically in the US)?

Comment: @paperskilltrees I explained that already. Collaborating with someone (=working with) is not the same as working for someone (= employment).

Answer (score 5):

A visa allows you to *live* in a country and (for the visa I assume you are getting) to be *gainfully employed* in that country -- that is, to draw a salary.

You do not need a visa to work on things while you are in your home country (working in your spare time, or in fact in a paid position). In other words, you can work on whatever project you'd like even before you get the visa. You just can't move to the target country yet, and you would have a separate conversion with your PI about getting paid if that's what you'd like.

Comment: Generally, getting paid requires a visa. The way to work around this is if your employer has a legal presence in another country and can employ you there. Generally, universities don't have such arrangements.

Comment: @Thomas: Neither of these are true. Universities are free to pay whomever they want abroad. They do not need a visa. They can simply be a contractor, and the university also does not have to have a legal presence in that country: the university only has to obey the labor rules in the country of the person being paid, but it doesn't not have to have a presence there. --- Separately, during the current pandemic, most universities have formed relationships with outsourcing companies that ensure adherence to local laws (health insurance, retirement contributions, tax deductions, etc.).

Comment: If only employment law were so simple...

Comment: @Thomas: Exactly _because_ it's out-of-country typically makes it easier. In determining what's covered under employment law, the law typically takes into account a number of factors. Your typical researcher doesn't work exactly prescribed hours, and since this involves another country, it means the university also doesn't decide where the work is done. Assuming some academic freedom, it also means the university doesn't really decide what will be done. So on the common "where,when,what" tests, the position does not appear to be that of an employee, but more that of an contractor.

Comment: @MSalters Employment law is complex and neither of us is qualified to make definitive statements about it. We haven't even specified which country (and state) this is in -- even a professional employment lawyer wouldn't comment in such generality. However, I have never heard of postdocs being classed as contractors, rather than employees. In the US, contractors must pay their own taxes and health insurance (only employees get taxes withheld and and employer-sponsored healthcare) -- I'm sure I would hear complaints from postdocs if this were the case.

Comment: @Thomas Do you have any citation for a visa being needed to pay someone in a country that is not the one issuing the visa? As far as I know, a visa is basically equal to printer paper outside of traveling to/in the country that issued the visa.

Comment: @user3067860 This discussion is well beyond the scope of comments. Ask a question on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not saying that one can be an *employee* without a visa. I'm just saying that there are ways to *get paid* while working from abroad. You can certainly work as a contractor with the university paying for the value of the contract. That's no different than the university paying a foreign company for 100 rolls of toilet paper. Neither the university nor the toilet paper company have to be incorporated in one of the two countries for this kind of exchange.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'm not qualified to say how such an arrangement would work, but I can confidently say it would be complicated and the university's HR department may not be willing to do it.

Comment: @user3067860 Here's a citation for "it's complicated": https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/hr-topics/global-hr/pages/paying-employees-abroad.aspx

Comment: @Thomas I believe it's complicated re: things like payroll tax, but _not re: visa_. And your comment is being used by other answers to justify saying that the OP will need a visa to work for a company from Y while living in X as a citizen of X (wtf). I already checked yesterday and there are already a couple of duplicates on Law (I will come back and post them later, no time now) but unfortunately no answers on the best duplicate. (Some _bad_ duplicates w/answers, like "I've been overstaying in the US for five years, can I return to my home country and keep working with the same US company?")

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case where **legally** and **officially**, you cannot be working as a postdoc before you receive the visa. **Unofficially**, no one is stopping you from working on a specific topic, or with unpaid collaboration, assuming you want to do this. If your aim is to continue research, such as to boost your publication record, most PIs would be willing to offer advice for getting started.

However, any work you do should be purely voluntary on your side (you can always say no to work until you are officially employed).

Answer (score 0):

Please note one point: a visa is required to perform work (paid or not is not that relevant) in a certain location in the world.

Contrary to what the majority seems to think, if you are working remotely, you still need a visa, depending on where you are based and ***NOT*** on where your employer / client is located.

In other words, you can work remotely from the US for a Chinese company, as long as you have an US visa.
Similarly, you can work from India for an US company, as long as you have an indian visa ... come on guys (&girls), the whole outsourcing business is based on this cornerstone!

Comment: In the outsourcing business, it's a common practice that a company A (for example in the US) will contract a company B (for example, in India) to do the work. In this case, visa considerations are irrelevant, because nobody works remotely for a foreign company.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper visa considerations are not irrelevant at all. To work for company B you need to have a valid permit to work from wherever you are in the world. Usually, people has the right to work in the whole of their own country (not always applicable, see the old Soviet Union or current modern China).